# Is Oprah's site made in Joomla!

Tags: content-management-system, joomla

I have got a project from a model who wants to build a site similar to oprah.com

I went through oprah.com and tried to find the CMS it is using but failed miserably. Does anyone has any ideas?

Moreover, which Joomla! components can be used to mimic the Oprah's site?

Comment: Just because your client wants the site to *look* as oprah's doesn't mean it needs to use the same framework. Use whatever you know and are comfortable in... then stylize it however you please. Anyway, I don't see anything extravagant about that site.. looks more like WordPress to me.

Comment: Doesn't look like Joomla or WordPress to me, looking at the source (no references to "com_" or "wp-content". Looks more like like custom work as the <head> is quite clean and most OSS CMS the <head> gets crammed full of stylesheets and scripts for external components / plug-ins.

Comment: I didn't even look at the code :) Looks like a fairly simple blog with a few other details sprinkled around.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom built site, which was built ofver several years.  I do not know about the CMS, but it does use J2EE, Oracle DBMS and Autonomy’s IDOL search and personalization engine and Jive’s Clearspace collaboration software for discussion forums and blogs.  I would predict therefore that the CMS is either bespoke or another paid for CMS solution.  I agree with pharalia - it is definately not an php-based open-source product such as Wordpress or Joomla

Answer (score 0):

You could easily replicate this look in Joomla, or Wordpress or Drupal for that matter. Since I know Joomla best and you asked, I would use K2 with a couple of different display modules for a site like this. [RokStories](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-showcase/9019) and [RokTabs](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/tabs-a-slides/9014) come to mind but there are all kinds of K2 compatible modules out there now.

That said, I'm not sure I would want to replicate a site this old. It makes some really basic mistakes that Oprah might be able to get away with, but someone with less star power is going to have problems.